# How to make a phone call programmatically?

Tags: android, phone-call

I'm passing to an activity the number to call by a bundle

and then, in such activity, I have a button to call to that number, this is the code:

```
callButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_CALL, Uri.parse(bundle.getString("mobilePhone")));
            }
        });
```

Something is wrong, because when I press the button nothing happens...

What am I doing wrong?

PD: I'm using Android 1.5 compatible project... maybe phone call is incompatible to 1.5?

Comment: pls paste logcat o/p or elaborate ur error details

Comment: In the selected answer, there is not check for marshmallow permission. It will not work directly in marshmallow 6.0 or above device. **I know I am too late but this question has large vote so I thought it will help to others in future.** In marshmallow devices we need to take run time permission for call... Here is example to make call in marshmallow or above. [How to make call in android marshmallow 6.0 or above](http://androiderstack.com/index.php/2017/08/02/how-to-make-call-in-android-marshmallow-6-0-or-above/)

Answer (score 272, accepted):

You forgot to call startActivity. It should look like this:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_CALL);

intent.setData(Uri.parse("tel:" + bundle.getString("mobilePhone")));
context.startActivity(intent);
```

An intent by itself is simply an object that describes something. It doesn't do anything.

Don't forget to add the relevant permission to your manifest:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CALL_PHONE" />
```

Comment: Hi @Lior how could i do in-case that device has dual-sim. Is it possible to make call through a particular sim?

Comment: @Dinash: Take a look at this already answered question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13231962/call-from-second-sim

Comment: I have used the same code but not working in the Galaxy S7 edge. 
This is my code 
Intent intentCall = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_CALL);
                    String uri = "tel:" + number.trim();
                    intentCall.setData(Uri.parse(uri));
                    if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(getApplicationContext(), Manifest.permission.CALL_PHONE) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                        startActivity(intentCall);
                    }

Comment: Can this simulator be used to make calls without physical device

Comment: Using this intent requires flag FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK because it is outside the app.

Answer (score 25):

Tried this on my phone and it works perfectly.

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_CALL);
intent.setData(Uri.parse("tel:900..." ));
startActivity(intent);
```

Add this permission in manifest file.

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CALL_PHONE" />
```

Comment: number is like 1689,,3,2,1,1 . I am getting issue it will be only 1689..Please help me if you have any solution for the same.

Comment: @TeraiyaMayur you can remove any non-numeric characters first. So if you have phone number as `String number = "1689,,3,2,1,1` do `nubmer = "tel:" + number.replaceAll("[^0-9]", "");`

Comment: @Walk, a problem is that we want to call with special symbols like `,*`. They must be among digits. On an emulator it works right, but on a device it drops additional symbols and digits.

Answer (score 13):

```
 Intent callIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_CALL, Uri.parse("tel:"+198+","+1+","+1)); 
             startActivity(callIntent);
```

for multiple ordered call

This is used to DTMF calling systems.
If call is drop then, you should pass more " , " between numbers.

Comment: Dwivedi Ji : number is like 1689,,3,2,1,1 . I am getting issue it will be only 1689..Please help me if you have any solution for the same.

Comment: @TeraiyaMayur, It's depends upon IVRS call system. Its work for me because of my calling extinction support take early response.

Comment: Yes you are right i also get proper valid IVR number and it works fine. thanks

Answer (score 3):

Take a look there : http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/intents/intents-filters.html

DO you have update your manifest file in order to give call rights ?

Answer (score 3):

This doesn't require a permission.

```
val intent = Intent(Intent.ACTION_DIAL, Uri.parse("tel:+123456"))
startActivity(intent)
```

Or

```
val intent = Intent(Intent.ACTION_DIAL, Uri.fromParts("tel", "+123456", null))
startActivity(intent)
```

But it shows one more dialog (asking whether you want to call phone just once or always). So it would be better to use `ACTION_CALL` with a permission (see [Revoked permission android.permission.CALL_PHONE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33473436/revoked-permission-android-permission-call-phone)).

Answer (score 3):

It is working very well. In this way, you *do not need to have permission* from user. You can open directly phone calling part.

> Trick point, use ***ACTION_DIAL*** instead of *ACTION_CALL*.

```
private void callPhoneNumber() {
    String phone = "***********";
    Intent callIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_DIAL);
    callIntent.setData(Uri.parse("tel:" + phone));
    startActivity(callIntent);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Here I will show you that how you can make a phone call from your activity. To make a call you have to put down this code in your app.

```
try {
    Intent my_callIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_CALL);
    my_callIntent.setData(Uri.parse("tel:"+phn_no));
    //here the word 'tel' is important for making a call...
    startActivity(my_callIntent);
} catch (ActivityNotFoundException e) {
    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Error in your phone call"+e.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
}
```

Comment: @Astor i have defined it very clearly, an i have already gotten points through this, which means that my answer is some what better than the other for some people.

Answer (score 1):

If anyone is looking for **in Kotlin**

```
    val  uri = "tel:+800******"
    val call_customer_service = Intent(Intent.ACTION_CALL)
    call_customer_service.setData(Uri.parse(uri))
    startActivity(call_customer_service)
```

Like some other solutions it requires `android.permission.CALL_PHONE` permission.

Answer (score 0):

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main); 
   final Button button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_call);
    button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            String mobileNo = "123456789";
            String uri = "tel:" + mobileNo.trim();
            Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_CALL);
            intent.setData(Uri.parse(uri));
            startActivity(intent);
        }
    });*
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

If you end up with a SecurityException (and the call does not work), You should consider requesting the user permission to make a call as this is considered a dangerous permission:

```
ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(
    activity,
    new String[] {Manifest.permission.CALL_PHONE},
    1
);
```

Note this has nothing to do with the manifest permission (that you must have as well)