# In android, how do I call myself programmatically?

Tags: android, call, self

I've seen an app that enables you to call yourself with the caller number "0123456789", how do I replicate this?

Comment: So how do you imagine talking to yourself?

Comment: Are you sure that the App wasn't designed to run from the Device emulator ?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to make a phone call programatically?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4816683/how-to-make-a-phone-call-programatically)

Comment: not a duplicate, I want to make a fake phonecall to myself

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The spoofing (fake number) is not something that happens on the device itself. It is something that happens via a telephony network. The app I've seen that does it calls some other number, which then spoofs the call to the number you wanted.

And if you mean nothing more than call your device from your device, then it would require a 3rd party telephone connection, because cell phone networks don't allow you to actually call yourself (it would usually go to VM). That, and as I described, the spoofed number requires an intermediary.