# How to detect which sim or sim slot is making outgoing call and sms in android

Tags: android, android-permissions, telephonymanager, dual-sim

[How to find out which SIM is making the outgoing call (Dual SIM)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18656373/how-to-find-out-which-sim-is-making-the-outgoing-call-dual-sim)

i have tried above and many other links but none of any worked for me...

Comment: Have you add sms permission in manifest file?

Comment: hey @madhankumar it's not about giving permission in manifest file it's all about how to detect sim slot or sim which making the outgoing call and sms using content observer in all  android device and ofcourse i have given all the required permission in manifest file. and please don't down vote question if u don't know the answer.