# Android - Calling through a specific sim in Lollipop

Tags: android-5.0-lollipop, dual-sim

How can I place a call using a specific sim with the new Lollipop api?

Maybe it's some **extra** that is needed - [as it is explained here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19474441/2482564)

Or some class I need to interact with?