# dual sim android phone which sim receive a call

Tags: android, telephonymanager

I have an android application that detect the incoming calls, i need to improve this app to work on a duos mobile device.
so i create a broadcast receiver registered in manifest for actions: phone state changed and on my onReceive method i need to check which sim receive the call. This is my code

```
   Protected void onReceive(Context c, Intent i)
   {
     Int whichSim = intent
      getIntExtra("simSlot",-1);
      // so this methof return 0            for sim 1 and 1 for sim2
     If(whichSim==-1)
    WhichSim=intent.getIntExtra("com.androie.phone.extra.slot",-1);
     }
```

I run this app on a device 4.2
2 and its working normally but when i run it on a device 4
4.4 so this method does not work, i mean that which sim return -1 in all cases. Can anyone help me?

Comment: Which brands / models are your devices?

Comment: Samsung duos galaxy J, SM-J100H

Comment: android version 4.4.4

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Android does not support dual sim phone until Android 5.1 and therefore any extension to support it may be device and version specific.  The following is specific for the class of phones using a variant of `MultiSimTelephonyManager` to handle dual sims, including Samsung duos galaxy J1 under Android  4.4.4.

Basically this class of dual sim phones use two instances of `MultiSimTelephonyManager`, subclassed from the regular [TelephonyManager](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/telephony/TelephonyManager.html) and each responsible for one SIM slot, as an interface to control the phone.

One of the means to detect the incoming call is to use the [PhoneStateListener](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/telephony/PhoneStateListener.html) class (instead of using a receiver) to detect change in phone states.  The `PhoneStateListener` in these phones are modified (rather than subclassed) to include a `mSubscription` field which should indicate the SIM slot of the listener.

Both the `MultiSimTelephonyManager` class and the `mSubscription` field of `PhoneStateListener` are not in the standard SDK. To compile the app to use these interface, Java Reflection is needed.

The following code should roughly illustrate how you could get the sim slot information from incoming calls. I do not have the device to test, so the code may need refinements.

Set up the listener during your initialization stage -

```
try {
    final Class<?> tmClass = Class.forName("android.telephony.MultiSimTelephonyManager");
    // MultiSimTelephonyManager Class found
    // getDefault() gets the manager instances for specific slots
    Method methodDefault = tmClass.getDeclaredMethod("getDefault", int.class);
    methodDefault.setAccessible(true);
    try {
        for (int slot = 0; slot < 2; slot++) {
            MultiSimTelephonyManager telephonyManagerMultiSim = (MultiSimTelephonyManager)methodDefault.invoke(null, slot);     
            telephonyManagerMultiSim.listen(new MultiSimListener(slot), PhoneStateListener.LISTEN_CALL_STATE);
        }
    } catch (ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException e) {
        // (Not tested) the getDefault method might cause the exception if there is only 1 slot
    }
} catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
    // 
} catch (NoSuchMethodException e) {
    //
} catch (IllegalAccessException e) {
    //
} catch (InvocationTargetException e) {
    //
} catch (ClassCastException e) {
    //
}
```

Override `PhoneStateListener` and set the `mSubscription` field to listen to phone state changes:

```
public class MultiSimListener extends PhoneStateListener {

    private Field subscriptionField;
    private int simSlot = -1;

    public MultiSimListener (int simSlot) {
        super();            
        try {
            // Get the protected field mSubscription of PhoneStateListener and set it 
            subscriptionField = this.getClass().getSuperclass().getDeclaredField("mSubscription");
            subscriptionField.setAccessible(true);
            subscriptionField.set(this, simSlot);
            this.simSlot = simSlot; 
        } catch (NoSuchFieldException e) {

        } catch (IllegalAccessException e) {

        } catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {

        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onCallStateChanged(int state, String incomingNumber) {
        // Handle the event here, with state, incomingNumber and simSlot
    }

}
```

You will also need to create a file named `MultiSimTelephonyManager.java` at the [project]/src/android/telephony directory.

```
package android.telephony;

public interface MultiSimTelephonyManager {
    public void listen(PhoneStateListener listener,int events);
}
```

You should probably do some error checking and especially check if the phone is the target model, when using the code. 
Please be warned (again) that the above would not work in most other phones and other Android versions of the same phone.

Comment: Hi, I've try to implement your solution. Now, There are a lot of errors in the logcat. I create a post in this thread (my log is too long for a comment). Pls see.

Comment: As I said the solution is for a specific device under a specific android version, and is not a general one for dual-sim phones. If you use the code as is in another device / version without checking, it will definitely end up with different exceptions.

Answer (score 0):

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13231962/call-from-second-sim) suggests `"com.android.phone.extra.slot"` may also work on some phones. Maybe try both and use the one that didn't return `-1`?

Comment: I also use this and does not work .. i hink there is new name for dual sim other than simSlot

Comment: Have you tried dumping all the intent's extras `intent.getExtras()`? Is there nothing there that's useful?

Comment: intent.getExtras() just return Incoming number and state(Ringing or idle), but does not return the sim id

Answer (score 0):

Have you Try this Method :-
in this method you will get 0 for 1 Sim and for second sim you will get 1.
//Working code For 4.4 Phones KitKat

```
   if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT) {
        whichSIM = intent.getExtras().getInt("subscription");


        if (whichSIM == 0) {
            whichSIM = 1;
            editor.putLong("ChooseSim", whichSIM);
            editor.commit();
            // Incoming call for SIM1

        } else if (whichSIM == 1) {
            whichSIM = 2;
            editor.putLong("ChooseSim", whichSIM);
            editor.commit();

        }
```