# MNC and MCC of a secondary SIM

Tags: android, telephonymanager

I know that using `TelephonyManager` we can get MNC and MCC of our network provider,

```
TelephonyManager tel = (TelephonyManager) getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);
String networkOperator = tel.getNetworkOperator();

if (networkOperator != null) {
    int mcc = Integer.parseInt(networkOperator.substring(0, 3));
    int mnc = Integer.parseInt(networkOperator.substring(3));
}
```

But I was able to get MNC and MCC data of only primary sim. I would like to know is there a way to fetch mnc,mcc,lac and cellid's of Secondary sim of a device in android.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Before API 22, it will be hard to achieve what you want.

I believe that before API 22, dual SIM was not originally supported by Android. So, each Mobile vendor should have its own implementation. Maybe, you should get their APIs/SDKs and include them to your project. Only this way, you will have access to their APIs.

From API22 onward, I think you can use SubscriptionManager

```
    int mccSlot1 = -1;
    int mccSlot2 = -1;
    int mncSlot1 = -1;
    int mncSlot2 = -1;

    SubscriptionManager subManager = (SubscriptionManager) getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SUBSCRIPTION_SERVICE);

    if(subManager.getActiveSubscriptionInfoCount() >= 1) {
        mccSlot1 = subManager.getActiveSubscriptionInfo(0).getMcc();
        mncSlot1 = subManager.getActiveSubscriptionInfo(0).getMnc();
    }

    if(subManager.getActiveSubscriptionInfoCount() >= 2) {
        mccSlot2 = subManager.getActiveSubscriptionInfo(1).getMcc();
        mncSlot2 = subManager.getActiveSubscriptionInfo(1).getMnc();
    }
```

Question https://stackoverflow.com/a/32871156/4860513 mention the same Android Limitation. So, I really believe it is not possible to achieve that before API22 with pure Android SDK.

Comment: Sometimes SubscriptionManager gives the same values for both SIMs. Some other times, it gives wrong values even when only one SIM is installed. That makes it unreliable to use.
I am testing against Android 5.1 on a Motorola Moto E device.

Comment: @BeshoyFayez Yes i also face same issue when i check this api to ViVo v5 mobile get same value for both sim. if you find any other code to get value of mcc/mnc please put here

Comment: I have android 6.0.1 face same problem this api give same mcc and mnc for both different operator(One is Airtel and other is Vodafone) sim

Comment: this method returning null. I am testing against android 8.0 Nokia3

Comment: The subId is not alway 0 or 1. SubscriptionManager.getDefaultSubscriptionId() returns 6 in my phone.

Comment: MCC number would be the same for both SIM (Bcz this Country Code), MNC could be different depends on operator type. 
More detail: https://www.mcc-mnc.com/

Answer (score 3):

SubscriptionManager subManager = (SubscriptionManager) getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SUBSCRIPTION_SERVICE);

```
    if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE)
            == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {

        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP_MR1) {
            if (subManager.getActiveSubscriptionInfoCount() >= 1) {
                List<SubscriptionInfo> subscriptionInfoList;
                subscriptionInfoList=subManager.getActiveSubscriptionInfoList();
                mccSlot1 = subscriptionInfoList.get(0).getMcc();
                mncSlot1 = subscriptionInfoList.get(0).getMnc();
                Toast.makeText(this, "Sim slot 1 " + mccSlot1 + " " + mncSlot1, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                mccSlot2 = subscriptionInfoList.get(1).getMcc();
                mncSlot2 = subscriptionInfoList.get(1).getMnc();
                Toast.makeText(this, "Sim slot 1 " + mccSlot2 + " " + mncSlot2, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            }
        } else {
            TelephonyManager telephonyManager = (TelephonyManager) getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);
            if (telephonyManager == null) {
                return;
            }
            String mCCMncCode = telephonyManager.getNetworkOperator();
            String mccCode = null;
            String mncCode = null;
            if (TextUtils.isEmpty(mCCMncCode)) {
                return;
            }

            final int MNC_CODE_LENGTH = 3;
            if (mCCMncCode.length() >= MNC_CODE_LENGTH) {
                mccCode = mCCMncCode.substring(0, MNC_CODE_LENGTH);
            }

            if (mCCMncCode.length() > MNC_CODE_LENGTH) {
                mncCode = mCCMncCode.substring(MNC_CODE_LENGTH);
            }
            Toast.makeText(this, "Lower than API 22 " + mccCode + " " + mncCode, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            return;
        }
    }
    else {
        ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, new String[]{Manifest.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE}, 1);
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

```
        SubscriptionManager subManager = (SubscriptionManager) getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SUBSCRIPTION_SERVICE);
        List<SubscriptionInfo> subscriptionInfoList=new ArrayList<>();
        subscriptionInfoList=subManager.getActiveSubscriptionInfoList();
        Log.d("LIST LIST",subscriptionInfoList.toString());
```

The Log was

```
[{id=4, iccId=89918782910310260628 simSlotIndex=0 displayName=Jio 4G carrierName=Jio 4G nameSource=0 iconTint=-16746133 dataRoaming=0 iconBitmap=android.graphics.Bitmap@2758949 mcc 405 mnc 861 SimProvisioningStatus 0 status 1}, {id=1, iccId=8991000826229271344 simSlotIndex=1 displayName=airtel carrierName=airtel nameSource=2 iconTint=-16746133 dataRoaming=0 iconBitmap=android.graphics.Bitmap@355e24e mcc 404 mnc 45 SimProvisioningStatus 0 status 1}]
```