# How to get Mcc and Mnc below LOLLIPOP_MR1 devices in android?

Tags: android, mcc, android-mnc

I am building an android application where I need to get Mcc and Mnc value of SIM. For single SIM I got perfect code but how to use that for dual SIM. 
I am using below code working fine above lollipop devices to get these two value.

```
  if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP_MR1)
    {
        SubscriptionManager manager = SubscriptionManager.from(this);
        List<SubscriptionInfo> sil = null;
        sil = manager.getActiveSubscriptionInfoList();
        if (sil != null) {
            for (SubscriptionInfo subInfo : sil) {
                Log.v("TestMain", "SubInfo:" + subInfo);
                Log.v("SIM_SLOT_INDEX"+ subInfo.getSimSlotIndex() +" mcc", subInfo.getMcc()+"");
                Log.v("SIM_SLOT_INDEX"+ subInfo.getSimSlotIndex() + " mnc", subInfo.getMnc()+"");}}
```

Can some one help me to finding below lollipop version how to can I get Mnc and Mcc value of Both SIM.

Comment: There was no native support for multiple SIMs in Android before API 22. Solutions will vary depending on the manufacturer/vendor.

Comment: @MikeM. can you provide me a common solution as I seen other application doing same.

Comment: There's not going to be a solution common to every pre-API 22 device. That was the point of my comment. The [answer linked](http://stackoverflow.com/a/32871156) in the duplicate above may provide you with decent coverage, but, as mentioned, it's not going to be universal. You'll have to decide which devices/OEMs you want to support, possibly investigate and implement their proprietary APIs, and test as needed.

Comment: @MikeM. I am getting error "java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: getDefault [int]"