# How to getSimOperator in dual SIM phone android?

Tags: android, dual-sim

I am building an android application where I need a value of "getSimOperator".

I am able to get this value > 21 API version but for the lower version in dual SIM. I am getting a value of SIM1 but not able to get SIM2 value.

How can I get "getSimOperator" value of SIM2 < 21 API version.

I earlier posted a question below is the link
[How to get Mcc and Mnc below LOLLIPOP_MR1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40902128/how-to-get-mcc-and-mnc-below-lollipop-mr1-devices-in-android?noredirect=1#comment69020789_40902128).

Someone has referred me a link [dual sim android phone which sim receive a call](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32707158/dual-sim-android-phone-which-sim-receive-a-call/32871156#32871156).

But I am getting an error while implementing the code of above link. I had listed down the error "java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: getDefault [int]"

Cloud anyone explains me why this error is coming.

Comment: that means the method is not available on your phone

Comment: @eriuzo I am also using this and try in many devices but not working for me. same error in every phone.

Answer (score 2):

here this link will might help you and refer the example no. 24 in this example http://www.programcreek.com/java-api-examples/android.telephony.TelephonyManager

Try this Github link.
https://github.com/illarionov/MozStumbler/blob/develop/src/org/mozilla/mozstumbler/cellscanner/GeminiCellScanner.java

In this following method return all info for available simcard.

```
 private List<CellInfo> getCellInfo(int presentSimNumsIndex){}
```

Another method is also which is as below.
For API >=17:

```
TelephonyManager manager = (TelephonyManager)context.getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);

// Get information about all radio modules on device board
// and check what you need by calling #getCellIdentity.

final List<CellInfo> allCellInfo = manager.getAllCellInfo();
for (CellInfo cellInfo : allCellInfo) {
    if (cellInfo instanceof CellInfoGsm) {
         CellIdentityGsm cellIdentity = ((CellInfoGsm) cellInfo).getCellIdentity();
        //TODO Use cellIdentity to check MCC/MNC code, for instance.
    } else if (cellInfo instanceof CellInfoWcdma) {
        CellIdentityWcdma cellIdentity = ((CellInfoWcdma) cellInfo).getCellIdentity();
    } else if (cellInfo instanceof CellInfoLte) {
        CellIdentityLte cellIdentity = ((CellInfoLte) cellInfo).getCellIdentity();
    } else if (cellInfo instanceof CellInfoCdma) {
        CellIdentityCdma cellIdentity = ((CellInfoCdma) cellInfo).getCellIdentity();
    } 
}
```

In AndroidManifest add permission:

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
     <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
</manifest>
```

To get network operator you can check mcc and mnc codes:

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mobile_country_code

https://clients.txtnation.com/hc/en-us/articles/218719768-MCCMNC-mobile-country-code-and-mobile-network-code-list-

Comment: I think it was for SIM1 only not for SIM2

Comment: Thanks, I will check and update you soon @Dharmishttha

Comment: I use your code but still getting MCC and MNC value for SIM1 not SIM2. How to get MCC and MNC for SIM2

Comment: Before API 22, it will be hard to achieve what you want.

I believe that before API 22, dual SIM was not originally supported by Android. So, each Mobile vendor should have its own implementation. Maybe, you should get their APIs/SDKs and include them to your project. Only this way, you will have access to their APIs.

Comment: How can I know which API/SDK and How to add to my project

Comment: I import GitHub project but there are many error coming while building.