# Android to identify calls received in sim1 or sim2

Tags: java, android, android-intent, broadcastreceiver, android-broadcast

I am trying to code `APK` to identify the received calls are in sim 1 or sim 2. I have tried below solutions but in all devices, it is not working. Samsung and MI devices the below solution is not working. can you please suggest universal solutions. thanks

I tried below solutions

[URL1](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/548416/Detecting-Incoming-and-Outgoing-Phone-Calls-on-And)

[URL2](http://www.theappguruz.com/blog/detecting-incoming-phone-calls-in-android)

```
public class IncomingCallInterceptor extends BroadcastReceiver {
@Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    String callingSIM = "";
    Bundle bundle = intent.getExtras();
    callingSIM =String.valueOf(bundle.getInt("simId", -1));
    if(callingSIM == "0"){
        // Incoming call from SIM1
    }
    else if(callingSIM =="1"){
        // Incoming call from SIM2
    }
    }
}
```

Comment: Are your Samsung and MI devices dual sim?

Comment: Try this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/54166869/7746134

Comment: @Wijdan yes my mobiles are dual sim.

Comment: Also they should have API 22 and above.

Comment: @SaurabhThorat I will try. thanks

Comment: @Wijdan do you have any code example ?

Comment: Please Log the whole bundle and check if it contains the key and value you are looking for like this : Log.d("Sim",bundle.toString());