# Call from Slot 2 in android?

Tags: java, android, phone-call, ussd

I am building an android application where I am calling an USSD number. I am writing a java code for phone calls and it is taking the default SIM Slot saved in settings.

Now the problem occurs in DUAL SIM when I want to call from SIM SLOT 2 programmatically.

I googled a lot and I have the below code but it is working on Samsung phone only.

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_CALL);
intent.putExtra("com.android.phone.extra.slot", 1); //For sim 2
intent.putExtra("simSlot", 1); //For sim 2
intent.setData(Uri.parse("tel:" + "**********"));
```

Is there a standard code which will work on all android phone? I just checked true balance and they are doing that, can anyone show me how are they doing that?

Comment: There is no official documentation for dual sim supported mobiles.
[http://stackoverflow.com/a/19474441/6448399](http://stackoverflow.com/a/19474441/6448399)

Comment: @iubiub it dose not support in my google nexus phone.