# Dialing in ListView

Tags: android

I have a basic app which shows a list view of items and when clicked a toast is generated saying you clicked on .... Now I want it to dial given phone numbers when clicked. Here is the code

```
    CustomClickListener listener = new            CustomClickListener();
    tableView.setClickListener(listener);
    tableView.addBasicItem("Example 1", "Summary text 1");
    tableView.addBasicItem("Example 2", "Summary text 2");
    tableView.addBasicItem("Example 3", "Summary text 3");
    tableView.addBasicItem("Example 4", "Summary text 4");
    tableView.addBasicItem("Example 5", "Summary text 5");
    tableView.addBasicItem("Example 6", "Summary text 6");
    tableView.addBasicItem("Example 7", "Summary text 7");
    tableView.addBasicItem("Example 8", "Summary text 8");  
    tableView.addBasicItem("Example 9", "Summary text 9");
    tableView.addBasicItem("Example 10", "Summary text 10");
    tableView.addBasicItem("Example 11");
}

private class CustomClickListener implements ClickListener {

    @Override
    public void onClick(int index) {
        Toast.makeText(Example1Activity.this, "item clicked: " + index, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Possible duplicate of: [How to make a phone call programmatically?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4816683/how-to-make-a-phone-call-programatically)

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_CALL);

intent.setData(Uri.parse("tel:" + phoneNumber));
context.startActivity(intent);
```

Don't forget to add the relevant permission to your manifest:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CALL_PHONE" />
```

In your case, it might look like this:

```
private class CustomClickListener implements ClickListener {

    @Override
    public void onClick(int index) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_CALL);

        // I don't know anything about your custom tableView...
        String phoneNumber = tableView.getItemAt(index).getPhoneNumber();

        intent.setData(Uri.parse("tel:" + phoneNumber);
        ExampleActivity.this.startActivity(intent);
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you please tell me how can that be implemented with my code?

Comment: This code goes in your onClick() function.  Instead of "context", you'll use YourActivity.this.startActivity(intent).  Given the index clicked, extract the phone number from your tableView.

Comment: Still don't understand how, can you simply show me? Please