# Is it possible to programmatically make a call on background?

Tags: android, ios, phone-call

I know it's probably impossible for security reasons but I am asking anyway because I can't find an answer on google.
Is it possible to create an app (Android/iPhone) that starts an automatic call when the phone OS is locked?

possible scenario:

1. user opens the app.
2. the app executes a command in background that after 1 minute should start the call.
3. user locks the phone.

Will the app execute the phone call?

Comment: Under iOS there is no API for an app to start a call without the user giving permission to make the call which then runs the stand phone app.

Comment: What do you mean by "the phone OS is locked"? The keyboard?

Comment: with "phone locked" I mean that the user has pressed the sleep button to lock the phone and the screen is dark.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes it's possible for Android I think. You can use the [AlarmManager](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlarmManager.html) or an [Handler](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Handler.html) for the schedule problem. To decide which you have to take. Here an exceprt from the Android documentation:

> Note: The Alarm Manager is intended for cases where you want to have your application code run at a specific time, even if your application is not currently running. For normal timing operations (ticks, timeouts, etc) it is easier and much more efficient to use Handler.

For starting a call in Android you can take a look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4816683/how-to-make-a-phone-call-programatically).

Comment: Just to be sure we are understanding each other. If I lock the phone by pressing the sleep button on my Android phone (so that the user must insert the security code to unlock the phone again) will the code for the automatic phone call launched with AlarmManager or Handler still work?

Comment: I don't have enough experience with the use of Handlers to schedule Tasks, but with the AlarmManager it definitely executes.

Answer (score 0):

As Fenix told, You can do this with the help of AlarmManager and ACTION_CALL implicit intent.

You can give a try from adb using the below command,

> $  adb -d shell am start -a android.intent.action.CALL -d tel:900XXXX69X

But once you trigger a call, Dialer will become the foreground application and the screen will switch on.