# How to call from within the application?

Tags: android, android-intent, android-view

I have a button and EdiText. in the EdiText I enter a phone number. By clicking on the button I need to call on this phone. but does not cause CallActivity and call directly from the application. how to do it?

```
tel = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText);
...
public void clic(View view) {
     String number = tel.getText().toString();

    }
```

and

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CALL_PHONE"></uses-permission>
```

Comment: there is no two line code to do that, you have to write your own application which handles mic and speaker. Take viber for an example. if you want simple solution you have to go the android call app

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4816683/how-to-make-a-phone-call-programatically

Comment: @Murtaza Hussain: ok. I'm not hoping for 2 lines of code. can share links which way I look?

Answer (score 0):

For direct calling from your app, which will place a call **(But you have to add permission for it)**

```
 Intent callIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_CALL);
          callIntent.setData(Uri.parse("tel:"+Uri.encode(PhoneNum.trim())));
          startActivity(callIntent);
```

For opening DIAL screen, **(You don't have to add ANY permission for it)**

```
 Intent callIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_DIAL);
          callIntent.setData(Uri.parse("tel:"+Uri.encode(PhoneNum.trim())));
          callIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
          startActivity(callIntent);
```