# Can we make call without opening calling activity?

Tags: android, call

Is it possible to make call without opening calling Activity (i.e. `Intent.ACTION_CALL`) ?

I don't want to show any UI while calling. It just like making hidden call.

Searched a lot for this. But I am not getting proper answer for this.

Comment: be more specific.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to make a phone call programatically?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4816683/how-to-make-a-phone-call-programatically)

Comment: @SalvadorHernandez I didn't mean like that I just don't want to show the UI of calling. Its just like hidden call.

Comment: Sounds like a security concern if were possible

Answer (score 1):

Probably not possible. Your requirement only fullfill by modified OS(Custom ROM).

Comment: According to my knowledge.it need to modified calling feature of OS.So if U able to make modification in the OS ,it is OK ,otherwise not possible.Beacuse there is a need of hiding the calling UI.